# Node.js one file exporter for dependencies VS requiring each dependency in each module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to make the work with Node.js easier. 
And I want to make the code to be looking more readable.

This is an example of some router page:

```
var Token = require('../../app/dependencies/token-middleware');
var Ratelimit = require('../../app/dependencies/ratelimit-middleware');
var createUserHandler = require('./api/create-user');

app.post("/users", Token.validate(), Ratelimit.validate(), createUserHandler);
```

As you can see, there middlewares that will probably getting loaded over and over, like the token and rate limitter middlewares.

I just want to make it easier from the both sides:

1. Easier to register a new module / middleware / dependency
2. Easier to summon an exists module / middleware / dependency

So I thought about creating one file called: *dependencies.js*
and one file called *middlewares.js* and one file called *modules.js*

They will be stored in the app directory - which is the "head" folder of the project, and stuff in here would be used by any module in the whole server.

And there to do something like this:

```
// dependencies.js 

module.exports = {
  Db: psuedocode new db connection,
  Joi: require('joi),
  Router: psuedocode new express router,
  Cast: psuedocode new manager handling the responses,
  ...
}

// middlewares.js 

module.exports = {
  Token: psuedocode new token middleware,
  Ratelimit: psuedocode new rate limit middleware,
  ...
}

// users-router.js 

const { 
  Token,
  Ratelimitter,
  ...
} = require('../../app/middlewares');

const { 
  Db,
  Joi,
  ...
} = require('../../app/dependencies');
```

OR even make the parsing in the index-router.js file to be ES6 styled:

```
// index-router.js 

let { ... } = require('../../app/dependencies); // really not sure if this is the write syntax (please fix it if it doesn't)

// and then use:

console.log(Db) // will not be undefined!
```

This is more related to best practices but I am asking in Stackoverflow in order to see if there is something that can cause problems with this way of working - before I make a project using this.

Comment: And what is your question? No, this won't cause any problems if that was your question.

Comment: I am asking if I can define express router once in a file that will be shared and used by multiple deep files without getting any kind of express response headers error.